# Demystifying the NiFi Scheduler: Deep Dive into Implementation

Tags: scheduled-tasks, apache-nifi, scheduler, process-group

Currently I am exploring **Apache NiFi**, and I am specifically assigned with the **Scheduler** present in the dataflow framework. And there a couple of things I need to learn about the scheduler.

1. I need to know the backend implementation of the scheduler. When a particular processor has been scheduled using the configure schedule tab, how does the **communication** happens between the processor and scheduler.
2. How can I make to schedule a process group in NiFi(After going through the web I got to know there are no direct ways to implement it, so are their any ways possible to schedule a process group in Apache NiFi?)
3. How does the scheduler in Apache NiFi gets its life in a logical sense, what I mean to ask is that is it a instance of a particular class or does it uses a scheduling library (like quartz) to run.

**What I Tired**

- I explored the web and the official documentation of Apache NiFi for the internal working of the scheduler.

**What I Expected to happen**

- I expected to find dedicated articles or resources to get a deep understanding of the Apache NiFi scheduler, how it works, is designed (architecture) and what are its actual internal mechanism.

**What Actually Happened**

- Unfortunately I couldn't find articles or resources solely focused on the internal working of the Apache NiFi Scheduler.
- All I learnt is there are two key mechanism that are Scheduling Framework and Scheduling Service responsible for the communication happening in between the processor and the scheduler. But I couldn't find anything dedicated to explain these in detail.

Comment: `1.` new processor instance triggered by cron, timer, or event - no other communication. `2.` only processors could be scheduled `3.` own implementation https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/support/nifi-1.23/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-core/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/scheduling